# In Magento 2 how to unserialized the array to get a data?

Tags: magento2, array

my code:

```
<?php
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$data = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('bootsgrid_deliverydate/general/mapping_date');
print_r($data);
?>
```

output:

```
 'a:3:{
      s:18:"_1550496532530_530";
      a:1:{s:6:"field1";s:10:"27-02-2019";}
      s:18:"_1550641096153_153";
      a:1:{s:6:"field1";s:10:"26-02-2019";}
      s:18:"_1550641100928_928";
      a:1:{s:6:"field1";s:10:"28-02-2019";}
    }'
```

How to get a date alone?

another output:

```
a:3:{s:18:"_1550664988208_208";a:2:{s:6:"field1";s:7:"9:30 AM";s:6:"field2";s:7:"2:30 AM";}s:18:"_1550735728909_909";a:2:{s:6:"field1";s:7:"3:30 AM";s:6:"field2";s:7:"6:30 AM";}s:18:"_1550735856179_179";a:2:{s:6:"field1";s:7:"6:30 AM";s:6:"field2";s:7:"9:30 AM";}}
```

how can i get a field1 and field2 value in same array
[link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/263040/how-to-join-a-multiple-array-field-to-one-field);

Comment: how did you get this data? is it from a response of a request?

Comment: its a response of serialized  array @magefms

Comment: if you are using a json format post data you can use json_decode and get the date , like a:3->a:1->s:10

Comment: used just a  print_r($data) @magefms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

//get data of an unserialized array
$serialized_data = serialize(array('_1550496532530_530',array('field1'=>'27-02-2019'),
                                '_1550641096153_153', array('field1'=>'26-02-2019'),
                                '_1550641100928_928', array('field1' => '28-02-2019')));

echo  $serialized_data . '<br>';
// Unserialize the data
$data = unserialize($serialized_data);

// Show the unserialized data;
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);

for ($i = 1; $i < count($data); $i++) {
    echo '<pre>';
    echo $data[$i]["field1"];
    $i = $i+1;
}
```

or this one using **foreach**

```
$data = 'a:3:{s:18:"_1550496532530_530";a:1:{s:6:"field1";s:10:"27-02-2019";}s:18:"_1550641096153_153";a:1:{s:6:"field1";s:10:"26-02-2019";}s:18:"_1550641100928_928";a:1:{s:6:"field1";s:10:"28-02-2019";}}';

// Show the unserialized data;
$postData = unserialize($data);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($postData);

foreach ($postData as $date) {
    echo '<pre>';
    echo $date["field1"];
}
```

Comment: i wil check and update u

Comment: Please note that my answer is assuming that your $data is the unserialized data

Comment: anyway I will update it and add the unserialize

Comment: its not working

Comment: try this updated one

Comment: you will get an idea

Comment: @divyasekar this will do the logic you want. you can check in a php file

Comment: i will check and update u

Comment: okay hope it will work for you

Comment: its working fine @magefms  i need a another favour from you

Comment: how can i get a  field1 and field 2 data in same array  pls refer above question @magefms

Comment: ahh , you just have to add it in your foreach like this: `foreach ($postData as $date) {
    echo '<pre>';
    echo $date["field1"]. " — " . $date["field2"];
}`

Comment: and it should work

Answer (score 2):

The "Magento way" would be to create a Serializer object (depending on the way your data is serialized, for example `Json` or `Serialize`) and call the `unserialize` method there.
For example like this (of course you can inject the Serializer object in your constructor depending on your context):

```
$serializedData = 'a:3:{s:18:"_1550496532530_530";a:1:{s:6:"field1";s:10:"27-02-2019";}s:18:"_1550641096153_153";a:1:{s:6:"field1";s:10:"26-02-2019";}s:18:"_1550641100928_928";a:1:{s:6:"field1";s:10:"28-02-2019";}}';

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$serializer = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Serialize');
$dataArray = $serializer->unserialize($serializedData);
print_r($dataArray);
```

Anyway the result is the same as just using the php `unserialize` method.

Update with complete working code based on the updated code from the question:

> anyway if your data is not serialized in a correct way (for example whatever formatting whitspace inside the data) the deserialize will fail!

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$data = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('bootsgrid_deliverydate/general/mapping_date');
print_r($data);

//deserialize...
$serializer = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Serialize');
$dataArray = $serializer->unserialize($data);
print_r($dataArray);
```

Comment: this one is not working

Comment: can you paste your complete code which is not working please? If I just copy the 5 lines into a controller I get the array.

Comment: If you want to access a single value, you have to access it by key, for example `echo $dataArray['_1550496532530_530']['field1'];` Or iterate over the array, however you have an deserialized array and can do whatever you need with it.

Comment: i edit my code in above question

Comment: so, where is the problem? Take line 3 and line 4 from my code, replace ` `$serializedData` with `$data` and you are done, you will have an array - but I'll update my response and do that for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$data = 'a:3:{s:18:"_1550496532530_530";a:1:{s:6:"field1";s:10:"27-02-2019";}s:18:"_1550641096153_153";a:1:{s:6:"field1";s:10:"26-02-2019";}s:18:"_1550641100928_928";a:1:{s:6:"field1";s:10:"28-02-2019";}}';

$dataUnserialized = unserialize($data);
```

Here the result of `var_dump($dataUnserialized)`:

[image: result]

so you can access your data as a simple array, like:

```
$date = $dataUnserialized['_1550496532530_530']['field1'];
```

Comment: its explode first date because of this one ['_1550496532530_530'], how to get a all the dates @Siarhey

Comment: @divyasekar You can use the `foreach` or other construct provided by php.