# How to implode a array object

Tags: array

Here my code:

```
 public function getTime(){
       $store = $this->getStoreId();
       $mapping_time = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XPATH_HOURMAX, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $store);
       $postTime = unserialize($mapping_time);
       $time_array =array();
       foreach ($postTime as $key => $value) {
       $time_array[trim($value['field1'])] = 
     [
        trim($value['field1']),
        trim($value['field2'])
    ];
     }
       return $time_array;
}
```

Actual result :

[image]

output:

[image]

my expection is:

```
   value                  option
9:30 AM - 2:30 AM : "9:30 AM - 2:30 AM "
6:30 AM - 9:30 AM : "6:30 AM - 9:30 AM "
3:30 AM - 9:30 AM : "3:30 AM - 9:30 AM "
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly it sounds like within your foreach `$value` is an array with two values (keys `field1` and `field2`), and you would like both the value and label of the dropdown options to be a string with both values concatenated by a hyphen.

If this is correct you could do this in a couple of ways. Using simple concatenation:

```
$valueString = $value['field1'] . ' - ' . $value['field2'];
$time_array[trim($valueString)] = $valueString;
```

Or you could use php functions `array_values` and `implode`:

```
$valueString = implode(" - ", array_values($value));
$time_array[trim($valueString)] = $valueString;
```

Comment: thanks above logic help me  @rain2o